# error: unexpected operator

Tags: bash

```
test `find /mnt/backups/mysql/information_schema-20120521-*.sql -type f -mmin -1500`
```

I am trying to check the age of a file but I am getting "unary operator expected" and "unexpected operator" errors depending on bash / sh used in script.

How can I avoid it?

If I do not use wildcard "*" then all works fine but  have to use it.

Comment: Looks like find returns more than one filename.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish?  `test` expects a single string argument if you do not specify an operator.  On the other hand, `find` by itself is quite capable of reporting whether it found any files, if that is what you are attempting to find out.

Comment: you seem to have missed an obscure point about using `find`. The first argument must be a path, not a filespec. Something endind with `*.sql` is a filespec. In your comments below, you keep refering to variables. Do you mean `...*.sql` OR and env var, like $VAR. If you mean $VAR, it cannot be inside single-quotes, as s-quotes prevent variable expansion. Either no quotes at all or the prefered solution is to use dbl-quotes, i.e. `"$VAR"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
find /mnt/backups/mysql/ -name "information_schema-20120521-*.sql" -type f -mmin -1500
```

And perhaps add --maxdepth if you want only files right under /mnt/backups/mysql/

Comment: if ! test `find '$DIR/$db-$date-*.sql' -type f -mmin -1500`

        Working fine alone but with variables it is not working.

    find: `$DIR/$db-$date-*.sql': No such file or directory

Comment: Working fine alone but with variables it is not working.

    #!/bin/bash

    date=`date +%Y%m%d`
    RESULT=0
    FILE=/tmp/mysqlstatus
    DBS="$(mysql -Bse 'show databases')"
    DIR=/mnt/backups/mysql
    for db in $DBS
    do



    if ! test `find '$DIR/$db-$date-*.sql' -type f -mmin -1500`
    then
    RESULT=$(($RESULT + 1))
    fi
    done
    echo $RESULT > $FILE

Comment: Use {}: $DIR/${db}-${date}-*.sql'

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the argument, as-is wildcards for `find` seem to cause issues with bash:

```
test `find '/mnt/backups/mysql/information_schema-20120521-*.sql' -type f -mmin -1500`
```

Comment: working fine alone but again with variable it is not working.

Comment: Try using double-quotes: `find "/mnt/...$VAR...sql"...`